# Adding all databases in an elastic pool to an availability group

Tags: azure-sql-database

Executing the Powershell get-help Add-AzureRmSqlDatabaseToFailoverGroup -examples gives three examples with #3

```
   PS C:\> $failoverGroup = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseFailoverGroup -ResourceGroupName rg -ServerName primaryserver  -FailoverGroupName fg
    PS C:\> $databases = Get-AzureRmSqlElasticPoolDatabase -ResourceGroupName rg -ServerName primaryserver  -ElasticPoolName pool1
    PS C:\> $failoverGroup = $failoverGroup | Add-AzureRmSqlDatabaseToFailoverGroup -Database $databases
```

"This command adds all databases in an Elastic Pool to a Failover Group."

Has anyone gotten this to work as presented?

I can successfully execute the Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseFailoverGroup & Get-AzureRmSqlElasticPoolDatabase steps but the third step returns a

```
Add-AzureRmSqlDatabaseToFailoverGroup : FailoverGroupUnableToPerformGroupOperationOnDatabases: The operation cannot be
performed due to multiple errors.
```

Comment: Hi jl -  Are setting up/working with Availability Groups of Failover Groups? The PowerShell is specific to Failover Groups. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/add-azurermsqldatabasetofailovergroup?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Comment: @Mike Ubezzi Cannot edit my question but it s/b failover group not availability group.  Adding the databases in an entire elastic pool to a failover group is where I am trying to get to.  My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you for the detail. I am investigating.

Comment: It should work. The error means `The list of databases to add/remove to/from Failover Group contains errors that are preventing operation to complete`. You can use `-Debug` for more details or create the new databases to have a try.

Comment: Joy thank!  -Debug never occurred to me.  Now just have to figure out why it expects my secondary server to be associated with the primary elastic pool.

Comment: @Joy Wang    My primary pool/server (scpool02/scsqlsrv02) is in region SC with ~50 databases.  The resource group is scrsg2.  The intended secondary elastic pool/server (ncpool02/ncsqlsrv02) is in region NC with zero databases.  The resource group is ncrsg2.  The results of the above Powershell execution is an error of "Elastic pool not found for server: 'ncsqlsrv02', elastic pool name: 'scpool02'."  Get-AzureRmSqlElasticPool -ResourceGroupName -ServerName  for each pool/server/resource group appears as one would expect.  Any ideas based upon what I have described?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Now just have to figure out why it expects my secondary server to be associated with the primary elastic pool." Azure expects DR server elastic pool name would be the same as your Primary elastic pool name. If name is different you will not be able add db's to failover group. 
I believe this is due to azure allow have multiple elastic pools on the same server and it have to know somehow in which one it should place database after you add it to failover group.
Hope it helps.

Comment: "Azure expects DR server elastic pool name would be the same as your Primary elastic pool name."  You are correct.  I did not find this to be clear in the docs when I was first going down this path.